# Tracking Down A Bad Function Call In CakePHP

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

I'm looking at the error.log for my CakePHP application, and seeing that I'm periodically getting this kind of thing:

```
2011-07-28 14:49:39 Warning: Warning (2): Missing argument 2 for NewsController::item()
in [/app/controllers/news_controller.php, line 771]
```

Seems fairly straightforward what's going on here: the item action used to just take an id parameter, and now it wants day, year, month, id.  Somewhere there must be a deprecated call to item passing just an id.

Unfortunately, I don't know where this somewhere is, in my increasingly sprawling application.  And the application doesn't seem to be breaking by not finding news items at any point.  So it seems like it might be somewhere really well hidden.

What would be the best strategy for efficiently locating the source of these error messages?

Comment: A silly question, but have you checked your `NewsController` for the method named `item`?

Comment: @Martin: Sure, the method is there, and it generally works (when it gets passed all four of its parameters.  I think I need to find the place it's being called from without all the relevant, and necessary, parameters being passed.  Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `grep 'item\(\$id\)' *php` or similar?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. I'm new to the world of CakePHP but I would have thought you should be able to some how get the script and line number the bad call was made.

Comment: Since its a controller action, the call is made by the core Router class when the user visits the correct URL (ie. `http://www.example.com/news/item/123`) and not by your application code.

Comment: Actually looking at my routes.php file it seems like urls in the form /news/:slug will get routed to the item method.  Searching on /news/ seems like a tactic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's caused by bad link somewhere in your application that didn't consider the additional parameters and your users clicking on them. For a start, you can start searching for things like `/news/item/` throughout your application views folder.

EDIT:
Or in your item() method, do a logging like `if(empty($thirdParam) || empty($fourthParam)) $this->log($this->referer);`, this way you can look into where the method is accessed from. It might not be always reliable, but yeah worth a try

Comment: Mmm, it's a sensible starting point but the issue is complicated by (reverse) routing, there are never any such simple things to search for.  However there may be some mileage in searching on variants of such things as 'controller'=>'news', 'action'=>'item'.  Just wondering if there any shortcuts to be had!

Comment: or in the case of links like `$this->Html->link(array('action' => 'item'))` you want to be searching for variations of `'action' => 'item'`.

Comment: Continuing on the broken link idea, it could be outdated links on other websites (ie. Google, etc). You should allow null values for `$year`/`$month`/`$id` and do a 301 redirect when requests with only a `$day` comes in.

Comment: Or in your item() method, do a logging like `if(empty($thirdParam) || empty($fourthParam)) $this->log($this->referer);`, this way you can look into where the method is accessed from. It might not be always reliable, but yeah worth a try

Comment: @andreas: Hmm, logging $this->referer is just giving me blank errors.  However you *have* given me the idea of logging the slug parameter being passed, which is a helpful clue to tracking down the source of the errors... thank you!

Comment: Yeah, logging the parameters being passed and looking at them helped me determine that the calls *aren't* being made from within the application (hence my difficulty searching for them).  They seem to be relics of the old site, which had links in the form /news/~slug.  Why we are still getting so many hits on them when that site has been taken down is still a bit of a mystery to me!

Comment: Check the Google index for your site, `site:example.com/news/`. Check the indexed URLs and also compare the number of results to your database. If that is where the hits are coming from, those visitors may be seeing a 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already, get familiar with a text-search tool that supports regular expressions:

- [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)
- [grep](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Grep)
- [Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/)
- [Notepad++](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/searching-files)
- etc.